# Reference Windows only project from NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, flaui

I have been working on tool that is done using NET MAUI. Now I would like to automate Windows UI, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have tried to download FlaUI NuGet, but can't get it working as it requires project to be `Net7.0-windows`. So I have created new project with reference to Net7.0-windows, but then my references in Net Maui get corrupted.

**MauiApp1.csproj** (project):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MauiApp1</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MauiApp1</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mauiapp1</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>67771146-3ce8-452f-860b-3669d8a9e4a0</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Project **ClassLibrary1.csproj** (project):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FlaUI.Core" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FlaUI.UIA3" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Currently if:

[image]

I get following errors:

[image]

My question is How to reference ClassLibrary1.csproj in MauiApp1.csproj in NET MAUI? Is there some way to get this setup working?

Comment: *"but then my references in Net Maui get corrupted"* What does that mean? If you attempted to reference Project Y, please show the .csproj lines for that reference, and show the complete error message you got.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have edited my question. Basically my target is to get FlaUI somehow working using NET MAUI

Comment: Puzzling. MauiApp1.csproj doesn't mention ClassLibrary1. Yet your screenshot shows it as a Reference. I don't know how that is possible, without it being in MauiApp1.csproj.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your  `ClassLibrary1` project going to support all platforms then you should add this lines to your  `ClassLibrary1.cspoj` file too.

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

If your `ClassLibrary1` project going to support just windows then you can do two things;

1. If your MAUI project just going to run on windows only, on your `MauiApp1.csproj` file you should delete these lines;

   ```
   <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>

   <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
   <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
   <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
   <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
   ```
2. If your MAUI App going to support other platforms at the same time, you should add your platform specific libraries separate. I am using this for my multiplatform MAUI apps.

   `Solution Explorer > Your MAUI Project > Dependencies > Right Click Your Platform > Add reference`

   then open your `MauiApp1.csproj` file, find your reference and add an condition to your reference. Your reference should be like this at the end;

   ```
   <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows')) != false ">
     <ProjectReference Include="..\MauiLib1\MauiLib1.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

---

**EXAMPLE**

I've made an example. I created a MAUI project named `MauiApp1` and a class library named `MauiLib1`. `MauiLib1` only supports Windows platform and `MauiApp1` supports all platforms. I've added `MauiLib1` to `MauiApp1` but for only Windows platform. Required `.csproj` files and platform specific codes can be seen below.

- `MauiApp1.csproj`

  ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
       <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>

       <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
       <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
       <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
       <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
       <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
       <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-windows')) != false ">
     <ProjectReference Include="..\MauiLib1\MauiLib1.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>
  ```
- `MauiLib1.csproj`

  ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>

       <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
       <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
   </PropertyGroup>
  ```
- A simple class in `MauiLib1` project. So we can make a test.

  ```
   public static class MauiLib1TestClass
   {
       public static string testString = "ehehehe";
   }
  ```
- Changed `MauiApp1` project's default `MainPage.xaml.cs` code a little bit. Here you can see Windows specific codes. Without these conditions your app will crash. Because there will not be a reference for that platform.

  ```
   #if WINDOWS
   using MauiLib1;
   #endif

   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
       int count = 0;

       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           count++;

           if (count == 1)
               CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
   #if WINDOWS
           else if (count == 3)
               CounterBtn.Text = MauiLib1TestClass.testString;
   #endif
           else
               CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

           SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
       }
   }
  ```
- After 3 clicks, you'll see our string in the button and here it's solution explorer's screenshot. As you can see reference added for windows only.

  [image: Desc] [image: Desc]

**Note 1**

Don't forget to change your current platform on the Visual Studio. It's very important. Otherwise, your platform specific codes will not be compiled.
[image: Desc]

**Note 2**

I deleted the parts unrelated to the question from the code. So everyone can see clearly what I've changed.

**Note 3**

If your library supports more than one platform you can add more conditions to your reference in the `.csproj` file.

Comment: For (2), can you show the lines that get added to .csproj?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for your comment. When I opened one of my projects, I noticed there are mistakes in my answer! I've corrected my answer and added an example.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Can you try to get it working with FlaUI installed in `MauiLib1.csproj`? For me it keeps saying `MauiLib1.csproj` should be `net7.0-windows` and not `net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0`

Comment: If [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FlaUI.Core#supportedframeworks-body-tab) page not wrong FlaUI is supported on only Windows 7 right now. MAUI apps supported Windows 10 1809 or higher versions. You can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms?view=net-maui-7.0). As far as I can see, these libraries are not compatible with each other. Somehow If you can run FlaUI on Windows 10, can you provide more details about it?

Comment: I'm not sure about it but if you look the FlaUI's nuget page, I guess they're planning support other platforms too. It's just not supported right now.

Answer (score 1):

I know little about FlaUI, but removing this line in `MauiApp1.csproj` might work:

`<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>`

Comment: What if I want to automate Mac and Windows UIs utilising different projects and libraries?

Comment: I know little about 'automate'. Will your code be completely different since you're using different 'automate' libraries? If yes, I might just create 3 different maui projects and share my common business code with another class library project.